# How to retrieve Skype status - SharePoint Framework webpart

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

We have this requirement to show a user's presence status in a SharePoint Framework webpart and am wondering what would be the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Check this.....
React Skype Status WebPart
This sample demonstrates how to use the UCWA JS SDK for skyp....
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-skype-status